# Changing the interrupt number for a specific device

Tags: x86

As far as I understand, hardware interrupts(as opposed to software interrupts) use  a hard-coded dispatch table to provide the requested resource, but I was wondering if I could change those values? Are these values OS specific or CPU  specific? Can the OS access this table?

Comment: Yes, of course the OS can change the table entries, it's just stored in ordinary RAM.  It can even change where the table is located, by running the LIDT instruction.  (Google it.)  In DOS, a program could "hook" an interrupt by installing its handler for that IRQ, and having its handler jump to whatever address was previously stored in the table.  (So you end up with a chain of handlers.)

Comment: Err wait, you're not talking about the interrupt number -> interrupt handler table, are you?  You're talking about how PCI interrupt pins or whatever are mapped to IRQ numbers, right?

Comment: @PeterCordes, yeah, the former

Comment: Oh, so you *are* asking about the IDT?  http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table.  I'm surprised you haven't been able to find the answer on your own with searches.

Comment: @PeterCordes, as far as I understand each device (NIC, GPU) have a different interrupt number, although it might be useless I wanna know if it's possible to change it?

Comment: So you meant "the latter", not "the former".  That's what I thought when I posted my 2nd comment.  Yes this is configurable somehow, but I don't know the mechanism.  PCI / PCIe plug-n-play work a LOT better than ISA pnp (where the device chooses which interrupt it's going to send and which I/O ports it will respond to).  Mapping hardware events to interrupt numbers might be part of ACPI, but at this point I'm just guessing.